# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Table Name Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, inflector

I'm on Windows XP...
Ruby 1.9.2
Rails 3.0.9
MS SQL Server 2005

I'm using **tiny_tds + activerecord-sqlserver-adapter**

In my database I have table named **t4**.
I have created a model like this: **rails generate model t4**
Here is my simple model **t4.rb:**

```
class T4 < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Here is migration file **20111013125957_create_t4s.rb:**

```
class CreateT4s < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up

 create_table :t4s do |t|
  t.timestamps
 end
end

def self.down
  drop_table :t4s
end
```

end

I have **schema.rb**:

```
...
create_table "t4", :force => true do |t|
  t.string "title", :limit => 50
end
...
```

**Problem:**
When I try T4.select("title").where(["id = 3"]) I get error message:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Invalid object name 't4s'.: SELECT title FROM [t4s] WHERE (id = 3)

**P.S.:**
I have another some tables named **Adddocs** and **Eclaims**.
There are not problems with queries to them.

I guess that problem is that **T4.select("title").where(["id = 3"])** maps to **SELECT title FROM [t4s] WHERE (id = 3)** (**T4** to **t4s**).
Why? I don't know

But when I edited file **config/initializers/inflections.rb** like this:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 't4', 't4'
end
```

Everything works! But it's not suitable solution (bad tone i think) :(((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new model it is the singular of the object your storing, whereas when it then generates the table, it uses the plural as there are multiple stored within the table. Example...

If you create a model named `user`, you'll end up with `app/models/user.rb` but the table it makes will be called `users`.

If you don't like that you have a few options...

- You can override the inflections as you've done, however you should only do this if Rails is getting the pluralization wrong, rather than forcing it to use a certain word.
- You can override the table name using the `set_table_name` method in the model file, providing it with a parameter of what your table name actually is.
- You could disable the whole pluralized table names with `config.active_record.pluralize_table_names = false` in your `config/application.rb` file, however I strongly recommend you don't do this.

Ultimately I would suggest using more descriptive table names which can be pluralized over ones that can't. `T4` as a model and table name don't explain to me what's stored within, where as `Post` does.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. If my table name (in database) is in singular (for example *view_list*), I have to make some changes that you have described in your post. Is it right?

Comment: The best solution would be to rename the table to 'view_lists', that way your `ViewList` model would match up. However, if that's not possible, I would override the table name in the model by using `set_table_name 'view_list'`.

Answer (score 4):

By convention, if you create a model named album, rails will create a table called albums.

To override this (which isn't usually done) and use a custom defined table name you can use **set_table_name** method like this in your model:

```
  class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
      self.table_name="album" * define here whatever table name you have
    end
```